# Spring security, thymeleaf and cookie

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Actually, I use spring boot, thymeleaf and spring security.
Security is splitted in two in the application.

One for mvc and other one for rest call.

I search a way if login is ok to create a cookie with login/password to be able to do add header to every ajax call.

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + $.cookie('cookie-authorization')
},
```

So i search to create a cookie if login success

Edit is it possible do to it on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code from the [`official doc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax) to include the tokens in all your Ajax calls.

```
$(function() {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
})
```

Hope this helps.